# twitterBot in java that automatically replies on call, and how to deal with duplicate errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter, twitter4j

I have gotten my twitter robot up and running called [newsMe](https://twitter.com/hirenabeel)

so the authentication is working all well, but It is not what I want..

the aim is to be able to call newsMe and make it reply with the latest news..
Im using the Jreddit Api for the news headlines and its working fine.. manually (using eclispe to run)...

so what I want now is 2 things....Please help..

1-- make it client independent.. i don't want to have to run eclipse every time it posts a news headline... so is there a way to make this available on call.. in stead of "run"ing of eclipse , I "Run" it on call by calling NewsMe?

2-- how do i get around the duplicate error, if the bot tweets the same headlines twice it will show an error and break (in eclipse), the thing is I don't know how it is recognizing duplicates!? so is there a way to loop over duplicates and continue to the next non duplicate headline?

im using twitter4j if thats any help.

Comment: 1) Nabster - I'm trying to understand your use case.  Is your desire that you are constantly monitoring a news site or similar, and posting articles to twitter when there are new ones?  If so, you'll need either a computer at your house or server on the web constantly running a compiled version of your java code (or on set intervals).
2) You can write code to check a new post against old ones.  Recommend doing some searching.

Comment: thanks kaz..

yes I am using the  JReddit api (WorldNews subreddit catagory) , and I want it to only post an article when I call it in twitter.. 

example: AccountA... posts @hirenabeel (this is my NewsMe twitterbot account)

so AccountA recieves the latest news headlines from reddits worldNews subreddit..

I have the Reddit posting so far, but it is only running of off eclipse (I have to run the program in eclipse) i.e nothing hapens when I call the twtterBot NewsMe

Comment: I was thinking it must be possible to use Heroku or similar , but I will consider using my laptop as a server ...I am doing it as an assignments so I only need to show it work... I can play around later..

I don't know what you mean but "write code to check a new post against old ones" and I don't thing its as straight forward as that...
if you mean parse the who page then that is too complicated and not a good solution...
in terms of storing data.. like in a json or using something else.. it would be too difficult to scale if people actually used this...

Comment: I would like this to be usable by all twitter users..

so i'm thinking.. since the twitter4j api is already recognizing duplicates it must have a method which it is using to recognize duplicates and so should be editable or overridable.

sorry had to split the comments.

Comment: any Help?? I am looking to complete a project and although this isn't mandatory (i have fulfilled the requirements with what I have ) I would much prefer to have these 2 features as it is much more practical.

Thanks